# powershell or msdeploy

Tags: deployment, powershell, iis-6

I am running into a situation where I need to find a better approach to deploy web applications (asp.net to iis6..sorry ruby lovers :( and I was curious what some of you have done? I have seen products out there (Anthill?) but I am really looking for a way that my operations team can script a way to grab zip files (packaged code and assemblies), unzip, deploy to a farm. Anyone have any thoughts or solutions that they may be using?

Answer (score 4):

Supposedly, MSDeploy ships with a PowerShell snapin and cmdlets... so you shouldn't have to choose.

- [IIS Team Blog: web deployment tool and PowerShell](http://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/archive/2009/10/07/web-deployment-tool-and-powershell-blog.aspx)
- [MSDeploy + PowerShell Blog](http://blogs.iis.net/jamescoo/)

The bad news is, I can't find that snapin on my system ;)

Answer (score 3):

You mention a tool that Microsoft has in Beta, [**`msdeploy.exe`**](http://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/archive/2008/10/29/the-web-deployment-tool-beta-2-is-now-available.aspx).  Is that not a good choice for you?

On IIS6, the state of the art was `adsutil.vbs`, `iisweb.vbs`, `iisback.vbs`, `iiscnfg.vbs`, and `iisext.vbs` or learning an arcane script programming model for IIS.

I think `msdeploy` will be a large step up from wrapping those primitive utils with powershell and other scripts or batch files, with its "syncing" approach.

Answer (score 2):

Also from VS 2010 standpoint, MSdeploy will be integrated into IDE so that would certainly be the direction to go...  Check out [Overview Post for Web Deployment in VS 2010](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/09/overview-post-for-web-deployment-in-vs.html).